# Custom Eclipse project type doesn't save (Plugin development)

Tags: eclipse-pde, eclipse-plugin

I've been following [this tutorial](http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-2-creating-a-custom-project-in-eclipse-adding-to-the-new-project-wizard/) to create my own custom project type and for the most part it works. Unfortunately when stepping through the my new project wizard it doesn't create a new project on "Finish".

My first thought was that I had missed this step:

> - Have **performFinish()** return true.

But I definitely have that done.

```java
public class NewProjectWizard extends Wizard implements INewWizard {
    @Override
    public boolean performFinish() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

There isn't much else to do. The test environment can create other project types just fine - like "Java" - their folders are created in `runtime-EclipseApplication` home folder correctly. I tried the Alt+Shift+F1 trick to look at other plugins' source and cannot see what the crucial step is.

What is missing? Are there other good resources which cover this? Nothing shows in the Error Log view, is there another log somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the actual work of creating the project in the performFinish() implementation. If you only seek to create a new Project, maybe you'd like to extend `org.eclipse.ui.wizards.newresource.BasicNewProjectResourceWizard` instead of the plain "Wizard"?

Comment: Thank you, that was it! If I need to be more specific in future I'll base it on that class and follow the tutorial with a touch of scepticism.

Comment: You're welcome, and following tutorials is indeed the easiest way of learning new things... In the Eclipse environment though, you can also easily take a peek at the implementations that are already available. For example, you knew you needed to somehow extend the Wizard class; you can open it (ctrl + shift + T and type in "Wizard") and see all of its subclasses in a glance by selecting the class name in the Java editor and hitting "F4" or "ctrl + t". This helps a lot when trying to see "how to do such or such thing" :).